# Authenticate a node app only with Google for work credentials

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm doing some preliminary research for a simple node file server for my company. We use *Google for work* logins, and I'd like to use these login to my node app. I am a bit lost as where to start. The google developer console seems much more powerful than I need.

Could anyone with experience give me a high-level explanation what I need to do?

Comment: google google+ sign-in for the easiest starting point.

Comment: Ta. And how do I restrict the logins to only users with our company's _Google for work_ accounts?

Comment: you get the email using one of the documented scopes. then check the email domain. there are cleaner ways if using google apps with multidomains.